# Find vector and parametric equations of span v

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How do I find vector and parametric equations of span $\{v\}$? Need help on steps to take or description.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in V$ and let $V$ be the vector space over field $F$.

$\text{span }v=\{kv\in V|k\in F\}$